# How to create resthook trigger in Zapier?

Tags: javascript, angular, zapier, zapier-cli

As I am trying to implement Zapier in my angular application. But I didn't get that how can I create rest hook trigger in Zapier and use that URL in my angular application.

I want to hit that rest hook URL every time new customer created and tell  the Zapier that a trigger fired.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

When you say

> implement Zapier in my angular application

I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you want to send data *to* Zapier, you can set up a zap with a webhook trigger which will provide you with a url (something like `https://hooks.zapier.com/hook/1234/abcd`).

You can POST data do that from Angular to trigger the zap.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't want zapier inbuilt hooks, I just want to create  my own hook.